# There is no editor available for filename.cs Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, c#

I get following error when I am trying to open my .cs file of design.
There is no editor available for filename.cs Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed

I was working in .cs file and system suddenly restarted. When I restart, I got above error.

I have tried to open .cs file in different tools. In Notepad++, I get NULL. In all other tools like notepad and wordpad etc, I get file blank.

It shows file size 291 KB. As this file was important, I need to recover it somehow. 
Can anybody suggest me way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please put notepad++ data too?

Comment: @JGC where should I put? File is blank. I can just open in Notepad++. it show NULL NULL NULL.

Answer (score -2):

If you have not used tools such as git or subversion I recommand to use windows restore point.
Else I think that you should use application for recovery such as GoBack.

Comment: I will use it after this experience. Is there any solution to recover now? @JGC